# How to update subscriber's attribute with the PHP FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, update

I'm having a hard time updating subscriber's attribute with this piece of code :

```
$client = new \ET_Client();

$subscribers = new \ET_Subscriber();
$subscribers->authStub = $client;
$subscribers->filter = array('Property' => 'SubscriberKey','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => $subscriberEmail);

$subscriber = $subscribers->get();

$subscriber->results[0]->Attributes[43]->Value = false;

$update = $subscriber->patch();
```

With this I'm getting this error : Exception occurred during [UpdateSubscriber] ErrorID: 227429849

I'm used to update with the SOAP API without problem usually.

Does someone can help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: Here's the full answer :                                                                                  ET_Patch object {
  status => (bool) false
  code => (int) 200
  message => null
  results => array(1) (
    [0] => stdClass object {
      StatusCode => (string) Error
      StatusMessage => (string) Exception occurred during [UpdateSubscriber] ErrorID: 227429849
      OrdinalID => (int) 0
      ErrorCode => (int) 2
      Object => stdClass object {
      }
    }
  )
  request_id => null
  moreResults => null
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I just learned through trial and error based on error messages:

The attributes need to be an array in the form of 'Name', 'Value' entries like so:

```
$subscriber->results[0]->Attributes = array(
     'Name' => 43,
     'Value' => false
);
```